# How to clear Unsaved draft for contact in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, contacts, contact-form

1. Open the default contact form to add a number
2. Add a number and click on cancel to remove and open new modal for confirmation
3. Select discard changes modal close

Now when I open the contact book then first open the modal with the last number I added in the contact book form which added from my app

here is my code:

```
    [self updateRecord:contact withData:contactData];

    CNContactViewController *controller = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForNewContact:contact];

    controller.delegate = self;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
        UIViewController *viewController = (UIViewController*)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
        while (viewController.presentedViewController)
            {
                viewController = viewController.presentedViewController;
            }
        [viewController presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:nil];

        self->updateContactPromise = resolve;
```

Below is delegate method code:

```
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if(updateContactPromise) {

        if (contact) {
            NSDictionary *contactDict = [self contactToDictionary:contact withThumbnails:true];
            updateContactPromise(contactDict);
        } else {
            
            updateContactPromise(nil);
        }

        updateContactPromise = nil;
    }
}
```